Determine a base for the action of $ G$
Problem:  Let $G := \langle (1,6,5)(2,3,4), (1,3,4)(2,5,6) \rangle \leq S_6$.
Determine a base for the action of $ G$ on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} $ and the order of $ G$.
Idea:
I know that the base will be $(1,2,3)$ and that it can be calculated using the Schreier–Sims algorithm. My idea to find the base was to compute all stabilizers using the simplified orbit algorithm, and then the base is simply the set of elements where their intersection is trivial. Does this approach work (and is there an easy way to calculate this intersection)? Also, is there an easier way to find the base without using the Schreier-Sims algorithm, as calculating all the stabilizers manually with the simplified orbit algorithm is very tedious and prone to errors?
I would really appreciate any help! :))

What is "a base for an action"?

The sequence $ m := (m_1, \dots, m_n) \in M^n $ is called a base of the operation if
$
\text{Stab}_G(m) :=  g \in G \mid g m_i = m_i \text{ for all } 1 \leq i \leq n } = {1}
$

Several  times you write "the base", but it is not unique. Any sequence that contains at least three distinct points is a base for this action, such as $(4,1,6)$ or $(1,3,5,2,4)$. But I don't think that there is any straightforward short cut for solving this problem, and you will have to use the Schreier algorithm to compute generators of a stabilizer. The Schreier-Sims algorithm is really designed for computers rather than for human calculation!

You only need to compute one stabilizer. I found that, after eliminating obviously redundant generators, the stabilizer $G_1$ of $1$ is generated by $(2,5,4,3,6)$ and $(2,4)(3,6)$. They generate a dihedral group, for which it is easy to calculate a base.

Yes, I also calculated all the stabilizers, and I noticed that they are dihedral groups, which allowed me to deduce the order of $G$. But to calculate their base we still need the schreier algorithm, right?

We have $G_1 = \langle a,b \rangle$ with $a=(2,5,4,3,6)$, $b=(2,4)(3,6)$, and note that $b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$. So $G_1$ is dihedral of order $10$, and hence $G_{15} = \langle b \rangle$ and $(1,5,2)$ is a base. (Of course $(1,2,3)$ is also a base.)
